# How does an application "create" a terminal command, and how could I use it in my own application?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, terminal, command-line

I have a basic terminal app, and would like to distribute it, but dislike having to run it with `./foo`.

What code could I add to the Makefile for the app, so that it would create a custom command that can run the app? (preferably cross-platform)

I have tried writing in code into the file: `.bashrc`, but it is too inconvenient for the user to manually do that. Concatenation to that same file is a good option either.

Comment: "Seeking the *PATH* environment varianble you are," said Yoda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual mechanism is to have an `install:` target in your `Makefile` which installs the script or binary into `/usr/local/bin`; but you also want to be able to allow the user to override this (so that, for example, a Debian package can use your `Makefile` but install to `DEBIAN/usr/bin` instead).

```
prefix ?= /usr/local
binpath=$(prefix)/bin
install: scriptfile
    install -m 755 scriptfile $(DESTDIR)$(binpath)
```

Here, `scriptfile` is a script or binary executable which you want to install in `/usr/local/bin/scriptfile` which should then make it available to any user with a sane `PATH`.

For good measure, probably also include `uninstall`;

```
uninstall:
    $(RM) -f $(DESTDIR)$(binpath)/scriptfile
```

If someone wants to install to their home directory, they can `make prefix=$HOME` or some such.

`DESTDIR` is a common convention for setting the installation root; so, for example, a Debian packager would set `DESTDIR=DEBIAN/` and `prefix=/usr`. (A more complex project might also install libraries in `$(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/lib`, man pages in `$(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/share/man`, etc.)

Mac and Windows distribution tends to look quite different. Simple applications can just be dragged to a folder which is already on the user's `PATH`; for anything more involved, you probably want to generate an installer for the target platform.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bin directory in your home directory

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
```

Move your terminal app to the newly created bin directory

```
$ mv /path/of/foo ~/bin/foo
```

Then add your local bin to your PATH environment variable by adding this to the end of your .bashrc:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

In a new terminal window try to find your command.

```
$ which foo
```

You should get output that looks something like this:

```
/home/username/bin/foo
```

NOTE: if you prefer you can create a symbolic link to your terminal app instead of moving it, like this:

```
$ ln -s /path/of/foo ~/bin/foo
```